# Copy function from STL to print out vector

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print out vector elements with copy function from STL. 
Theoretically it supposed to work without any malfunction, but I got weird notification, I google it but I really can't comprehend what failure did I make. 
Let me show what I'm on about:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 

int main(void)
{
   vector<string> names; 
   names.push_back("Jeremy"); 
   names.push_back("James"); 
   names.push_back("Richard"); 

   copy(names.begin(), names.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, ' '); 

   // this line cause some problems;


}
```

I got the following error:

invalid conversion from const char*' to char'

I would love to obtain some proper (easy to understand as well) explanation what is wrong with my idea ;)

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

1.Change:

```
copy(names.begin(), names.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, ' ');
```

into:

```
copy(names.begin(), names.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));
```

*(string literal, not character)*

2.add missing paren.

3.and add missing `<algorithm>`, `<iterator>` and `<string>` headers.

4.add `using namespace std;`

Comment: I'm wondering, is using `copy` and `ostream_iterator` to output container a common trick?

Comment: @MarsonMao: yes, it is an elegant STL way to print out container

Comment: @MarsonMao: it was before C++11, now I prefer `for (const auto& s: names) { std::cout << s << " "; }`

Comment: (OT) Mind you that C++ is still missing a standard elegant print function with seperators only between the entries like string.join in python.